# Not all cards visible within the list...Why Not?

Tags: trello-cards

After adding a new card to a list I noticed that it did not show up within the list.  I then noticed that only 4 cards are visible within the list even though the list says it contains 7 cards (as depicted at the top of the list to the right of the list name).

The newly added card shows up as the newest activity within the activity list, and I can get to the newly created card by clicking the link within the activity list BUT otherwise this card and apparently 3 others in this list are invisible.

Any ideas what is going on?

(looking at board in more detail I am missing cards on each list within the board.)

(Using Android App it seems I can see all 7 cards)

***FIXED*** Filter left on - hiding other cards   ***FIXED***